# Javascript code for Lowest Common Multiple

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for explanations on SO, but I've only found answers in other programming languages that don't quite clear it up for me.

I suspect it's the math behind it that I'm not getting, since the code is clear enough, but if someone wouldn't mind explaining, I'd be grateful.

(I added the comments in there to try to explain to myself what was going on, so if they're wrong, that would also be good to know.)

EDITED TO ADD: The expected input is an array of two numbers. The task is to find the lowest common multiple for all the numbers between those two values, inclusive. That's probably important to know. Sorry.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) { 
    var i = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var j = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var resultArr = [];

    // make an array of the numbers from high to low
    while (j >= i) {
        resultArr.push(j);
        j--;
    }

    return resultArr.reduce(function(x, y) {
        var a = x, 
            b = y, 
            t = 0; 

        // while a is not evenly divisible by b
        while (a % b) { 
            a = a % b;  // a is the remainder
            t = a;      // t is the remainder
            a = b;      // a is now the divisor
            b = t;      // the divisor is now the remainder
        }
        return (x / b) * y; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What is your expected input?  `arr` is an array representing what?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints throughout the code? If you throw that in jsbin, for example, sprinkle some "debugger" statements anywhere you're unsure of what's going on, then open up your console, and just poke around. that's probably your best bet

Comment: This code seems almost deliberately obtuse: mixes imperative and functional paradigms for no obvious reason with single-character variable names.

Comment: If you're trying to write an algorithm to find the lowest common multiple, there are much less complicated ways to do so. I suggest ditching this bit of code and trying a different (more reasonable) approach.

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I realized that I left out the larger context of the task, as well as a few other bits of relevant information. I've added them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment is not really correct. This line is creating an array of the numbers inbetween i and j, sorted high to low. That is, if you had array = [1, 10], resultArr would be [10, 9, 8. 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

Really, what you have there is the difference between the first and second number. This is the first step in Euclidean algorithm for finding the GCD (greatest commmon denominator)

The second part is in one step calculating the gcd as well as calculating the prime factors and getting the product of them.

Comment: Thanks, Belfordz. the Euclidean Algorithm was the mathematical part that I wasn't getting. I had thought about going the prime factors route, but that was even more difficult for me to translate into code that this was to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
function leastCommonMultiple(min, max) {
function range(min, max) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

function gcd(a, b) {
    return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

function lcm(a, b) {
    return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);   
}

var multiple = min;
range(min, max).forEach(function(n) {
    multiple = lcm(multiple, n);
});

return multiple;
}

leastCommonMultiple(1, 13); // => 360360
```

Comment: Thanks, Prasad. I was actually looking to understand what the code I posted was doing rather than just solve the problem.